# On browser, unable to access back camera using navigator.getusermedia js in latest Samsung s10 and s20 phones ( Note:3 back cameras in latest phones)

Tags: javascript, android, android-camera, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

In latest Samsung s10 and s20 phones, I facing back-camera blocked issue on browser while accessing using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia javascript. But able to access front-camera successfully. These s10 and s20 mobile have 3plus back-cameras.

Note: it worked well on Samsung s9 for both front and back camera, I believe it has single back camera, so no camera access issue in s9.

Below is the simple JS code used to access back and front camera.

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
      width: screen.width > ipad_size ? 1280 : { ideal: 640 },
      height: screen.width > ipad_size ? 720 : { ideal: 480 },
      facingMode: method == 2 ? "user" : { exact: "environment" },
    },
  })
  .then(function (stream){
    console.log("Access camera: ");
  
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Unable to access camera: " + err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
facingMode: method == 2 ? "user" : "environment",
```

is what I recommend.